# Where do System.out.println() messages go, when it is called in client-side GWT-module?

Tags: java, gwt, println

When I write messages to log (i.e. `com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.Log#debug`) I can see them in Chrome->F12->Console or (during debug) in IDEA->Debug->Dev Mode. But if the `System.out.println()` was used in IDEA the messages appear in the same place as the logged ones, but what about when I am not debugging? where do they go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.out.println()` are just removed by the compiler in production mode.

If you want to check just create this simple module:

```
public class Foo implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {

    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

And look at the generated javascript.

Comment: What about in Super Dev Mode? What happens to them then?

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to do logging (at development time) is `com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.log()`. Messages logged this way will also wind up in your browser's console like you mention. Likely `System.out.println` is mapped to the same functionality for convenience. From the `GWT.log` Javadoc:

> Logs a message to the development shell logger in Development Mode, or
>   to the console in Super Dev Mode. Calls are optimized out in
>   Production Mode.

Comment: Also consider the juli logging: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html